# Spin-1/2 rotation operator: rotation about an angle of $\pi$

Tags: operators, quantum-spin, spinors

The spin-1/2 rotation operator:
$$
R_{n}(\alpha)
 =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  cos(\frac{\alpha}{2})-in_{z}sin(\frac{\alpha}{2}) & (-in_{x}-n_{y})sin(\frac{\alpha}{2})  \\
  (-in_{x}+n_{y})sin(\frac{\alpha}{2}) & cos(\frac{\alpha}{2})+in_{z}sin(\frac{\alpha}{2})  \\
 \end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
R_{x}(\pi)|z;+\rangle
 =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & -i \\
  -i & 0 \\
 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 \\
  0 \\
 \end{pmatrix}
 =-i\begin{pmatrix}
  0 \\
  1 \\
 \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
R_{y}(\pi)|z;+\rangle
 =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & -1 \\
  1 & 0 \\
 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 \\
  0 \\
 \end{pmatrix}
 =\begin{pmatrix}
  0 \\
  1 \\
 \end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
R_{z}(\pi)|z;+\rangle
 =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  -i & 0 \\
  0 & i \\
 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 \\
  0 \\
 \end{pmatrix}
 =-i\begin{pmatrix}
  1 \\
  0 \\
 \end{pmatrix}
$$

What is the physical meaning of $-i$ multiplies the resultant states of $R_{x}(\pi)$, $R_{z}(\pi)$ operations ?

Why there is a mathematical difference in the resultant states of $R_{x}(\pi)$, $R_{y}(\pi)$ by a factor of $-i$ ?

Comment: The consequence of the factors of $i$ is that if you do a rotation by $2\pi$ (for instance look at $R_z$), you do not get back the same state as before, but negative of that state. This is a crucial difference in bosonic and fermionic representations.

Comment: @Prahar thank u. I understand that, its a spinor.$2\pi$ rotation must give a -ve sign to the origintal state. But, why is this difference between $R_{x}(\pi)$ and $R_{y}(\pi)$ ?

Comment: oh, I see. I misunderstood your question. That difference in the factor $i$ has no significance. That depends entirely on the representation that I use to describe the matrices.

Comment: @Prahar ok. i think, the $i$ factor does not affect the probability, so it does not have any physical meaning i guess.But why does it come only in the case of $R_{x}(\pi)$ compared to $R_{y}(\pi)$ mathematically ?

Comment: Thats because of the basis you chose. I mean, the labels $x$ and $y$ are really interchangeable.